# Call symputx throws error for macro variable

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to save a value from a varialbe to a macro variable by using

```
 call symputx
```

however SAS throws error

the program i wrote is this way

```
data want; 
set have;
array SR(*) &orde; 
bb=dim(SR);

call symputx('D',bb);

array M(symget('D'));
do i=1 to dim(SR);
M(i)=SR(i);
end; 

run;
```

it gives error as

```
array MXY_A(symget(D));
                        -
                        79
                        76
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: Did you try: array M(dim(SR)); ?

Comment: Yes., its the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a description or example for your input and desired output? so i give you the correct code.

Answer (score 2):

The dimensions of an array are set during the compilation of the data step, before it starts executing. Defining macro variables via `call symput` doesn't happen until the data step starts executing. If you want to use a macro variable to set the size of an array like this, you need to define it prior to your data step.

Answer (score 0):

The code below iterates through each value of the array then outputs it in a new row in the WANT dataset:

Code:

```
data want(keep=id new);
      array score{3} s1-s3;
/*array values: 99,60,82 */
      input id score{*};
         do i=1 to dim(score);
         new=score{i};
            output;
         end;
      datalines;
   1234  99 60 82
   ;
run;
```

Output:

[image]